# Meteor.subscribe doesnt work

Tags: meteor

If i visit the /whatever/:_id/result page nothing is gonna be rendered except the static text. Why doenst my Meteor.subscription work? Is there anything i am missing here?

```
Router.route('/whatever/:_id/result', {
  template: 'result',
  name: 'result',
    data: function(){
      var currentId = this.params._id;
      console.log(currentId);
        return Questions.findOne({_id:currentId});
    },
    WaitOn: function(){
      var currentId = this.params._id;
        return [ Meteor.subscribe('arguments', currentId), Meteor.subscribe('questions',currentId) ]
    },
    onBeforeAction: function(){
      this.next();
    }
});
```

On my server ive got:

```
Meteor.publish('arguments', function(currentId){
  return Arguments.find({decisionId:currentId});
});

Meteor.publish('questions', function(currentId){
  return Questions.find({_id:currentId});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a simple typo.

```
WaitOn: ...
```

Should be

```
waitOn: ...
```

with a lowercase w.

Comment: You should use ESLint - in my opinion it saves a boatload of time because it catches errors like this for you as you type.